# Where to fetch DNX_APPBASE after the RC1 update?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, dnx

Been running a asp.net 5 console application that is published to multiple environments for a while now.

However, since the RC1 update, the environmental variable DNX_APPBASE that I relied on for the config.(environment).json location has been removed.

Here is the code in question[image: Console Application]

Anyone know what happened to the DNX_APPBASE environmental variable and where I can get this information from?

Alternatively, what are other ways to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could add this into the constructor for Startup.cs

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.PlatformAbstractions;

public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env, IApplicationEnvironment appEnv)
{
    // Setup configuration sources.
    var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
       .SetBasePath(appEnv.ApplicationBasePath)
       ....
}
```

but in RC1 it is not needed to call .SetBasePath at all, so you could remove that.

Comment: Included it as you suggested, but it doesn't hit the method. Thought that was only used in a web environment and the Console Application entered through void Main? Must I change the command in project.json?

Comment: my bad, startup is only for web apps. what about var a = PlatformServices.Default.Application.ApplicationBasePath;

Comment: DNX_APPBASE was always "internal" and you should have been using the APIs to access the application base.

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. Wasn't aware of that API.